# r connected star free graph has perfect matching

Tags: graph-theory

Prove that an even-vertex $r$-connected graph without $K_{1,r+1}$ as an induced subgraph has a perfect matching.

I start by assuming by contradiction that it doesn't, then by Tutte's theorem there is some $S$ such that $o(G/S)>|S|$, with $|S| = k \ge r$ by $r$-connectivity and so $o(G/S) > k\ge r+1$. Let these odd components be $C_1,C_2,...,C_{k+1},..$

Then I know that if I pick an element from each $C$ then we have at least $r+1$ independent vertices that are connected to vertices in $S$, but I'm stuck when I try to get that they are all connected to a single vertex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you can directly verify that Tutte's condition holds.

Your $r$ is my $k$.

Let $S$ be a set of vertices.

If $S=\emptyset$, then $o(G-S)=0$, since $G$ is connected and even.

If $1\leq|S|<k$, then $G-S$ is connected, so $o(G-S)=1\leq|S|$.

Final case: $|S|\geq k$. Assume that $G-S$ has more than $|S|$ components.
Each component of $G-S$ must have at least $k$ edges to different vertices of $S$
or otherwise we could remove less than $k$ vertices from $S$ to disconnect $G$.
Choose $k$ such edges for each component.

Then each vertex $v$ of $S$ has at most one of those chosen edges to any component of $G-S$,
so in the bipartite (component/vertices of $S$)-graph where the edges are defined by our choice
we have more than $|S|k$ edges arriving at the $|S|$ vertices of $S$,
so at least one vertex has more than $k$ arriving edges, which produces a $K_{1,k+1}$. Contradiction.

So $G-S$ has at most than $|S|$ components, so certainly at most $|S|$ odd components
and we are done.

Comment: Thanks, arrived to the same solution just as you posted :)

Comment: Maybe you should wait longer before posting a question :)